# How to Remove status bar from Particular View controller?

Tags: ios4

I am trying to remove status bar from particular View Controller but still it shows blue line when i tried to Hide it so please give some suggestions for that.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to Hide the Status bar from Every View 
try putting the code in your appdelegate file. in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method as follows

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}